# date object initialized in javascript

Tags: javascript, date, object

I'm formatting a date object in JS, but the date changes its value in the way:

```
str = '05-10-2013';
 s = str.split('-')
 nbr = Number(s[0]) + '-' + (Number(s[1]) - 1) + '-' + Number(s[2]);
 // nbr has now the value : 5-9-2013
 // so I create the date object from the str               
 var dateObj = new Date(nbr);
 // the dateObj has the value: Tue Apr 04 1911 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Paris, Madrid (heure d’été))
```

And I have some truble understanding why the value of the date is initialized when the date object is created.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Does the initial date refer to 5th October or to 10th May?

Comment: Why pass in a string when Date accepts a year/month/day constructor?

Comment: Really! Why would you split on `-` when the date uses `/` as a seperator ?

Comment: @adeneo I tried with the '/' but all I got was NaN so i thaught maybe is the separator..

Comment: @Alucard You get `NaN` because you are trying to split a string that doesn't have `-` character by `-`, hence your `s[0]` is exactly `05/10/2013` which becomes `NaN` after casting to number.

Comment: @VisioN That was dumb from me.. Didn't pay attention

Comment: It was the reverse order as in @Dolondro answer.. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of converting it back to a string again, just pass it into the function normally.

```
str = '05/10/2013';
s = str.split('/')
dateObj = new Date(s[2], s[1]-1, s[0]);

//dateObj: Date {Sat Oct 05 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)}
```

Comment: It was the reverse... Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It seems the date string is just in reverse order, and you could fix that with

```
var str = '05/10/2013';
var date = new Date(str.split('/').reverse().join('/'));
date.setMonth(date.getMonth() - 1);
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/bNt3C/1/)

Comment: // nbr has now the value : 5-9-2013 what is your solution or this ?

Comment: @samitha - why would I need a solution for that ?

Comment: i don't know why he mentioned that kind of thing in his question but he doing s[1]-1

Comment: @samitha - Oh, I see, subtracting months, days, whatever is done the usual way once the date object is initialized.

Answer (score 1):

You can use str variable as Date object constructor's argument:

```
var dateObj = new Date(str);
```

Date constructor with string argument accepts month/day/year; So if you want that 05/10/2013 matchs 5th October use "10/05/2013" string. Or:

```
str = '05/10/2013';
s = str.split('/');             
var dateObj = new Date(s[1]+'/'+s[0]+'/'+s[2]);
```